# Best way to check in bash if Command Line Tools are installed?

Tags: macos, terminal, xcode, bash

Using bash, I want to check if Command Line Tools are installed.

Currently **they are** and when I type `xcode-select --install` I get:

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use
>   "Software Update" to install updates It appears Homebrew is already
>   installed. If your intent is to reinstall you should do... blah blah
>   blah

**Basically my problem is that I have several methods to check in bash (using `if / fi`) but I don't know which solution is the best one.**

1) I can do `xcode-select -p` and that returns the path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` but then how I should build the `if` statement? I don't know what will be presented when CLT are not installed.

2) I can do `xcode-select --version`. Should I then `grep` for a phrase `version` since I get

> xcode-select version 2343.

3) I can do `which xcode-select` but again, in all cases I'm not sure how the `if` should look like. I also think that `grep` is not the best way, since in the future the output may be different in future version of OSX.

To sum up I would like something like

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ no idea ]; then
    #installed, nothing to do...
else
    xcode-select --install
fi
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if type xcode-select >&- && xpath=$( xcode-select --print-path ) &&
   test -d "${xpath}" && test -x "${xpath}" ; then
   #... is correctly installed
else
   #... isn't correctly installed
fi
```

Strangely, the `--print-path` isn't documented in old Xcode versions but is working as `-print-path`. On the other hand, the `-p` option doesn't
have this compatibility.

Comment: That's perfect. So I was missing that `-x`. Thank you Daniel. I see that replacing `-print-path` with just `-p` works as well.

Comment: Depending on the quality of the checking you want to achieve, a `type xcode-select` and a `-d` could be necessary.

Comment: I'd use: `if [ -d "$(xcode-select -p)" ]; then`

Comment: If you want to use `print−path` it's supposed to be `−−print−path` not `−print−path` as you have it.

Comment: @user3439894: thank you. On many of my `Xcode` versions, the `man` documents `-print-path`, some others document `--print-path`. But in all cases `-p` seems more trustable.

Comment: With the help of remarks of @user3439894, I put here or more general shell check of `Xcode` correct install.

Comment: Shouldn't `${xpath}` be double quoted to prevent globbing and word splitting?  Also, why are you placing spaces around `xcode-select --print-path` in `$( xcode-select --print-path )`?  There doesn't need to be and should simply be: `$(xcode-select --print-path)`

Comment: @user3439894: about quotes you are right. About the spaces around `$(` and `)` it is a personnal habit (as the space before `;`) so as to visually separate them of the rest of the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Just because code-select returns a valid path doesn't mean the command line tools are installed:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$ if type xcode-select >&- && xpath=$( xcode-select --print-path ) &&
    test -d "${xpath}" && test -x "${xpath}" ; then echo "installed" ; fi
installed
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
```

Thus, a more accurate check is to use xcode-select to try and install the CLT with the following:

```
if xcode-select --install 2>&1 | grep installed; then
  echo installed;
else
  echo not installed, installing;
fi
```

If it's not installed, it will prompt for installation as your example shows, but without a separate line for the `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Is the first code you run the consequence of a 1st `xcode-select --install` followed by a move of the registered `Xcode` path with `xcode-select --switch /tmp`?

Comment: In macOS Sierra 10.12.2, if CLT is already installed `xcode-select --install 2>&1` results in stderr: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`, but you wouldn't want to suppress that either for the case when it isn't installed. I'm stumped.

Comment: @fd0 looks to be the way to go.

On a clean Sierra MacOS 10.12.1:

    ENTER: $ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
    RESULT: No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
    ENTER: $ echo $?
    RESULT: 1

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach would be to use `pkgutil`

```
if      pkgutil --pkg-info com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables >/dev/null 2>&1
then    printf '%s\n' "CHECKING INSTALLATION"
        count=0
        pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables |
        while IFS= read file
        do
        test -e  "/${file}"         &&
        printf '%s\n' "/${file}…OK" ||
        { printf '%s\n' "/${file}…MISSING"; ((count++)); }
        done
        if      (( count > 0 ))
        then    printf '%s\n' "Command Line Tools are not installed properly"
                # Provide instructions to remove and the CommandLineTools directory
                # and the package receipt then install instructions
        else    printf '%s\n' "Command Line Tools are installed"
        fi
else   printf '%s\n' "Command Line Tools are not installed"
       # Provide instructions to install the Command Line Tools
fi
```

Comment: I looked in the source code of homebrew and `Homebrew/os/mac/xcode.rb` looks to use this type of approach. Looking at homebrew was interesting to me as I could see the evolution of the CLT integration in MacOS.

Comment: The command line tools are not always installed with the `com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables` package. They may instead be part of Xcode…